# setting the appdir in Dancer::Test

Tags: perl, dancer

I have an dancer webapp that I'm trying to test, and I have a few issues related to paths.  It appears that the appdir setting isn't being set correctly.

The top of my test code is:

```
use MyApp;
use Dancer::Test;
```

if I dump out the settings (using dd from Data::Dump) from:

```
my $settings = Dancer::Config::settings();
dd $settings;
```

I get:

```
{  appdir        => "/Library/WebServer/Documents/myapp/lib",
apphandler    => "Standalone",
auto_reload   => 0,
charset       => "",
confdir       => "/Library/WebServer/Documents/myapp/lib",
content_type  => "text/html",
daemon        => 0,
engines       => {},
envdir        => "/Library/WebServer/Documents/myapp/lib/environments",
environment   => "development",
handlers      => {},
logger        => "file",
plugins       => {},
port          => 3000,
public        => "/Library/WebServer/Documents/myapp/lib/public",
server        => "0.0.0.0",
server_tokens => 1,
startup_info  => 1,
template      => "simple",
traces        => 0,
views         => "/Library/WebServer/Documents/myapp/lib/views",
warnings      => 0}
```

clearly it's not setting the appdir correctly.  It doesn't appear that it matters how I call code (i.e. the working directory).

I've been calling it as `perl -I lib -I ../lib t/001_base.t`  with the additional library calls as MyApp.pm needs modules in both `lib` and `../lib`.

When I run the same code as a standalone webapp which is the following in `bin/app.pl` which has the code:

```
use Dancer;
use MyApp;
dance;
```

dumping the settings gives me the right appdir, which loads the configuration file and sets all of the other correctly.

In my test code, I thought that adding the lines:

```
Dancer::set appdir=>"/Library/WebServer/Documents/myapp"
Dancer::Config->load;
```

would do it.  However that sets the appdir correctly, but doesn't change any other parameters.  From the `Dancer::Test` code, there is an import command which appears to do what I want, but didn't help at all. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Hmm, works for me with a new Dancer app. Can you reproduce this behavior with a new app? Also, I can't find any documentation for `Dancer::Config::settings`...you generally shouldn't use undocumented functions.

Comment: Looks like I tracked down my error.  It seems to be coming from loading in additional routes.  I originally wrote my other routes as packages and loaded with `use`, but appears I should be using `load` instead.  Some of this code dates back a couple of years and maybe things have changed.